# Node.js script copy from redis to elasticsearch runs out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, node-redis

I have a simple node script that's going to copy non-exist document from redis to elasticsearch. However, my script failed because of memory. I realised that Node.js has a limitation of 1G of memory. I have about 1.7G of documents in redis (According to Redis)

```
# Memory
used_memory:1828855608
used_memory_human:1.70G
used_memory_rss:1768804352
used_memory_peak:1839670312
used_memory_peak_human:1.71G
```

Here's my simple node script

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('redis');
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const config = require('../config');

let client = redis.createClient({
  host: config.redis.url,
  port: config.redis.port
});

let esClient = elasticsearch.Client({
  host: config.elasticsearch.url
});

client.keys('*', (err, keys) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    esClient.exists({
      index: 'articles',
      type: 'article',
      id: key
    }, (err, exists) => {
      if (!exists) {

      } 
    });
  });

});
```

And this is the error I got.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   56742 ms: Scavenge 1398.8 (1457.2) -> 1398.8 (1457.2) MB, 0.8 / 0 ms (+ 2.2 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   57796 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1457.2) -> 1398.8 (1457.2) MB, 1054.1 / 0 ms (+ 3.2 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.2 ms) [last resort gc].
   58835 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1457.2) -> 1398.8 (1457.2) MB, 1038.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x220f52737399 <JS Object>
    1: test [native regexp.js:~132] [pc=0x2b04c4f8bd00] (this=0xdea7c8c02e9 <JS RegExp>,k=0xdea7c8b0741 <String[24]: /articles/article/1HcdBc>)
    2: new constructor(aka ClientRequest) [_http_client.js:~19] [pc=0x2b04c4fa5ebd] (this=0xdea7c8c0459 <a ClientRequest with map 0x11d7d52ec4f1>,options=0xdea7c8c0409 <an Object with map 0x11d7d52f6731>,cb=0xdea7c8c03c1 <JS Function (SharedFunctionInfo...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
sh: line 1: 96220 Abort trap: 6           node scripts/copy-to-es.js
```

However, that 1.7G from Redis is the entire of documents but I thought I was just getting all the keys to check if it exists in Elasticsearch or not. I'm not sure why it failed because of memory and how do I overcome this? I'm using Node 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the elasticsearch client might be in cause. There is a bug report describing the issue you are having. Which release of elasticsearch client do you use ?

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/310

Answer (score 0):

if it's only one or two ES calls, I'd try using plain HTTP requests (with request or superAgent) to ES instead of using the elasticsearch module...

However, I would also check how much memory the redis keys will occupy: your code will load all of them in memory at once...